# Create pandas DataFrame from raster image - one row per pixel with bands as columns

Tags: python, numpy, rasterio, digital-image-processing, pandas

I have a raster image with 3 bands. I would like to convert this image to a `csv` file where each row will be one pixel and each column will be one band, so that I can easily see the three values each pixel got.

This is how I have tried to do it:

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.features
import rasterio.warp
from matplotlib import pyplot
from rasterio.plot import show
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


img=rasterio.open("01032020.tif")
show(img,0)

#read image 
array=img.read()

#create np array
array=np.array(array)

#create pandas df

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [array[0]], 'Column2': [array[1]],'Column3': [array[2]]})
dataset
```

and also like this:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [array[0,:,:]], 'Column2': [array[1,:,:]],'Column3': [array[2:,:]]})
```

but i'm getting something weird like this table:
[image]

I have also tried:

```
index = [i for i in range(0, len(array[0]))]
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': array[0], 'Column2': array[1],'Column3': array[2]},index=index)
dataset
```

but then I get the number of the rows I have and it's still not good:
[image]

what do I do wrong?

#### My goal

Get one pandas table, where each row is a pixel, and it should have 3 columns, one for each band.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Quick solution

```py
pd.DataFrame(array.reshape([3,-1]).T)
```

### Explanation

1. Take array of shape `(3, x, y)` and flatten out the 2nd and 3rd dimension. From the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape): *One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.*

```
reshaped_array = array.reshape([3,-1])
```

2. Transpose array to get array of shape `(x*y, 3)`

```
transposed_array = reshaped_array.T
```

3. Build DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame(transposed_array)
```

Comment: thank you for yoir aswer, is ther any way to preserve the coordinates?

Comment: You will need one or two extra columns that store the index/indices of the original image. I think that's for a new question. -> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 4):

Or another simple solution with [numpy ravel()](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
import rasterio as rio
src= rio.open('myraster.tif')
# number of bands
src.count
3
# read bands
array = src.read()
# convert to a DataFrame
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['band1'] = array[0].ravel() 
df['band2'] = array[1].ravel() 
df['band3'] = array[2].ravel() 
df.head(2)
           band1 band2 band 3
0           250   249   254
1           250   249   254
df.tail(2) # last
           band1 band2 band 3
78609002    190   182   180
78609003    190   186   174
```

Or

Answer (score 1):

You can check that here [http://shreshai.blogspot.com/](http://shreshai.blogspot.com/2014/11/converting-raster-dataset-to-xyz-in.html)

The implementation is for a multiband raster and also keeps the coordinates

```
with rasterio.open(RASTER_PATH) as src:
    #read image
    image= src.read()
    # transform image
    bands,rows,cols = np.shape(image)
    image1 = image.reshape (rows*cols,bands)
    print(np.shape(image1))
    # bounding box of image
    l,b,r,t = src.bounds
    #resolution of image
    res = src.res
    res = src.res
    # meshgrid of X and Y
    x = np.arange(l,r, res[0])
    y = np.arange(t,b, -res[0])
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    print (np.shape(X))
    # flatten X and Y
    newX = np.array(X.flatten())
    newY = np.array(Y.flatten())
    print (np.shape(newX))
    # join XY and Z information
    export = np.column_stack((newX, newY, image1))
```